# Bash script to calculate average mark

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with a lot of marks. The objective of the script is being able to print in the screen the average mark of each student.

```
Charles:1:8:9
Daniel:1:3:3
Josh:4:6:1
Alfonso:7:5:1
Eric:6:8:5
```

I've tried the following piece of code:

```
cat /home/sysadmin/MARKS.txt | while read line
do
  # These extracts the 3 marks of each student.
  mark1=`cat /home/sysadmin/MARKS.txt | cut -d":" -f2`
  mark2=`cat /home/sysadmin/MARKS.txt | cut -d":" -f3`
  mark3=`car /home/sysadmin/MARKS.txt | cut -d":" -f4`

  # Calculate average.
  let add=$mark1+$mark2+$mark3
  let avgMark=$add/3

  # Print average.
  echo $avgMark
```

But in the screen, the cript only returns 0 in every student, like this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

Any help would be appreciate, many thanks in advance!! And happy new year!!

Comment: Can you try echoing the intermediate variables too to work out what's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are ok with `awk`(where we need not to use so many commands in a loop), you could try following, could be done in a single `awk` itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print "Average for student "$1 " is: " ($2+$3+$4)/3}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{             ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=":"           ##Setting FS as colon here.
}
{
  print "Average for student "$1 " is: " ($2+$3+$4)/3
                   ##printing student name(1st column) and printing avg(adding 2nd, 3rd and 4th column) and dividing it with 3 here.
}
' Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 4):

With bash and an array (`$col`):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i av   #  set integer attribute

while IFS=":" read -r -a col; do
  av=(${col[1]}+${col[2]}+${col[3]})/3
  echo "${col[0]}: $av"
done < MARKS.txt
```

Output:

```
Charles: 6
Daniel: 2
Josh: 3
Alfonso: 4
Eric: 6
```

---

See: `help read`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Perl`:

```
$ perl -F: -lanE  '$sum=0; for $i (1 .. $#F) 
                     {$sum+=$F[$i]} 
                   printf "%s: %.2f\n", $F[0], $sum/$#F;' file

Charles: 6.00
Daniel: 2.33
Josh: 3.67
Alfonso: 4.33
Eric: 6.33
```

Or, perhaps a little fancier output:

```
$ perl -F: -lanE  '$sum=0; for $i (1 .. $#F) 
                      {$sum+=$F[$i]} 
                   printf "%-10s%.2f average with %i scores\n", 
                          $F[0].":", $sum/$#F, $#F;' file
```

Which is also a method that you could do in `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: '{sum=0
           for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum+=$i
           printf "%-10s%.2f average with %i scores\n", 
              ($1 ":"), sum/(NF-1), NF-1}' file
```

Both those print:

```
Charles:  6.00 average with 3 scores
Daniel:   2.33 average with 3 scores
Josh:     3.67 average with 3 scores
Alfonso:  4.33 average with 3 scores
Eric:     6.33 average with 3 scores
```